# Android: Press Back Button onCreate method is not called

Tags: android, back-button, oncreate

I tested of my application in my Samsung device. I realized that when I pressed on back button of my device, application does not recall the `OnCreate` method on previous activity. It just resumes previous activity page only. May I know how can I call onCreate method of previous page when I click on back button. Thanks

Comment: So why You want to recall onCreate of this activity? If You want to refresh soem things, You should do a method instead the refresh all the stuff. OR, finish the activity and start it again when You press the back button of the other one....

Comment: by the way, You should read some stuff about activity lifecycle. If You come back to an activity, onResume() will be called, so maybe You can do that stuff inside that too.http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Comment: Because I am adding some information to previous page activity on current page. Therefore, when I press on the back button, it will display the latest information I added. However, Android does not call OnCreate method when I press on back button.

Comment: What ever you need to do when you activity starts and resumes should be placed in 'onResume()' since it will be called after `onCreate()` as well.

Comment: Move your updateLatestInformation function call into onResume instead of onCreate. That might work, but without seeing the code it will be very hard to give anymore information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it sounds like you are opening a second activity to get some information and then applying the changes to the previous activity.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

If not you should look at the Activity lifecycle so that you understand where to put your update code:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html